# ¿Cómo conectar Docker y pgadmin en Linux?

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, pgadmin

He instalado tanto Docker como pgadmin, ahora quiero conectar ambos.
Para ello, hago lo siguiente:

```
sudo su -

docker run --name xx-xxxxxxxx -e XXXXXXX_USER=xxxxxxxx -e XXXXXXXX_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:9.5.5
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/my-postgres" is already in use by container "7ab93b28acca2fdafbcc3724ef94a4c27ddb4335c62efefb15fc73778b5df0dd". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le estás dando el nombre al docker con la siguiente directiva `--name xx-xxxxxxxx`

Como te indica la salida del comando, tienes un conflicto de nombres. Si listas los dockers que tienes con el comando [docker ps -a](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

Tendrás en esa lista el nombre que le has dado al docker `xx-xxxxxxxx`.

- Puedes eliminarlo (si NO lo necesitas) usando el comando [docker rm xx-xxxxxxxx](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/)
- Puedes utilizar un nuevo nombre para el contenedor que deseas correr.

---

Ejemplo:

- Hacemos un `docker run`:

```
$ -> docker run --name testdocker -d alpine
b1522037c2a3fce7f8865ca7a84b9b71eba3c2904c0b54cdca334f6bb6c50a73
```

- Si lo intentamos de nuevo, vemos que nos da el error:

```
$ -> docker run --name testdocker -d alpine
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/testdocker" is already in use by container "b1522037c2a3fce7f8865ca7a84b9b71eba3c2904c0b54cdca334f6bb6c50a73". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

- Vemos que tenemos ya un docker con ese nombre:

```
$ -> docker ps -a | grep testdocker
b1522037c2a3   alpine                                "/bin/sh"                About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago             testdocker
```

- Podemos eliminarlo:

```
$ -> docker rm testdocker
testdocker
$ -> docker ps -a | grep testdocker
$ ->
```

Comment: Lo he borrado usando rm como indicas, pero ahora, vuelvo a un nuevo error:
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my-postgres (a65844b5f3c83a80dab012598b8e0913a6291ef944b97e95597a0eb6c19d9867): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use.

Comment: Estás intentando mapear de nuevo el puerto 5432. Ya se está utilizando con algún otro servicio, sea el host en local u otro docker. Ejecuta el comando `netstat -nlp | grep 5432` para comprobarlo.

Comment: netstat -nlp | grep 5432
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR    1206/postgres       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    33290    1206/postgres        /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` Parece ser que sí, entonces lo que he de hacer es cambiar el número del puerto?

Comment: O no hizo un release del puerto al hacer `docker rm` o tienes postgre corriendo en el host. Si lo tienes en el host haz un `stop` del servicio sino mata el proceso que esté corriendo ese puerto por si no hizo el release.